# AttributeError: 'LocalAccount' object has no attribute 'privateKey'

Tags: web3py

```py
def register(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Register the user and generate a ETH address."""
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    if update.message.chat.type != 'private':
        update.message.reply_text('This command can only be used in a private chat.')
        return
    # Check if user is already registered
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = %s', (user_id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is not None:
        update.message.reply_text('You are already registered.')
        return
    # Generate new ETH address and private key
    account = w3.eth.account.create()
    address = account.address
    private_key = account.privateKey.hex()
    # Check if address is valid
    if not Web3.isAddress(address):
        update.message.reply_text('Error: Invalid ETH address generated. Please try again.')
        return
    # Insert new address and private key into database
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO addresses (user_id, address, private_key) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (user_id, address, private_key))
    db.commit()
    # Insert new user into database
    username = update.message.from_user.username
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id, username) VALUES (%s, %s)', (user_id, username))
    db.commit()
    # Send confirmation message
    message = f'You have been registered with the following ETH address:\n\n{address}\n\nPlease use this address to deposit ETH or ERC20 tokens to your account.'
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=message)
```

How can I fix this ?

Try to fix this but still cannot fix we got error for:
`AttributeError: 'LocalAccount' object has no attribute 'privateKey'`

Comment: We need more information about what all of these objects are and it would be better if you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But generally if you some errors like this: double check that you are using the right attribute name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Web3 6.0 released, `LocalAccount.privateKey` has been renamed to `LocalAccount._private_key`.

[For further info, refer to Web3 6.0 released notes](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releases.html).

Comment: thanks for answer and give detailed we try for fix this. thankyou